# Auditing in Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers, audit, auditing

I need some help in auditing in Oracle.   We have a database with  many tables and we want to be able to audit every change made to any table in any field.   So the things we want to have in this audit are:

- user who modified
- time of change occurred
- old value and new value

so we started creating the trigger which was supposed to perform the audit for any table but then had issues...

As I mentioned before we have so many tables and we cannot go creating a trigger per each table. So the idea is creating a master trigger that can behaves dynamically for any table that fires the trigger.   I was trying to do it but no lucky at all....it seems that Oracle restricts the trigger environment just for a table which is declared by code and not dynamically like we want to do.

Do you have any idea on how to do this or any other advice for solving this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need write your own triggers.

Oracle ships with flexible and fine grained audit trail services. Have a look at [this document](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96521/audit.htm) (9i) as a starting point. 
(Edit: Here's a link for [10g](http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cfgaudit.htm) and [11g](http://sqltech.cl/doc/oracle11g/network.111/b28531/auditing.htm#DBSEG006) versions of the same document.)

You can audit so much that it can be [like drinking from the firehose](http://drinking-from-the-firehose.urbanup.com/1867465) - and that can hurt the server performance at some point, or could leave you with so much audit information that you won't be able to extract meaningful information from it quickly, and/or you could end up eating up lots of disk space. Spend some time thinking about how much audit information you *really* need, and how long you might need to keep it around. To do so might require starting with a basic configuration, and then tailoring it down after you're able to get a sample of the kind of volume of audit trail data you're actually collecting.

Answer (score 6):

If you have 10g enterprise edition you should look at Oracle's [Fine-Grained Auditing](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/Auditing_10gR2.php#fine_grained_auditing).  It is definitely better than rolling your own.

But if you have a lesser version or for some reason FGA is not to your taste, here is how to do it.  The key thing is: *build a separate audit table for each application table*.

I know this is not what you want to hear because it doesn't match the table structure you outlined above.  But storing a row with OLD and NEW values for each column affected by an update is a really bad idea:

1. It doesn't scale ( a single update touching ten columns spawns ten inserts)
2. What about when you insert a record?
3. It is a complete pain to assemble the state of a record at any given time

So, have an audit table for each application table, with an identical structure.  That means including the CHANGED_TIMESTAMP and CHANGED_USER on the application table, but that is not a bad thing.

Finally, and you know where this is leading, have a trigger on each table which inserts a whole record with just the :NEW values into the audit table.  The trigger should fire on INSERT and UPDATE.  This gives  the complete history, it is easy enough to diff two versions of the record.  For a DELETE you will insert an audit record with just the primary key populated and all other columns empty.

Your objection will be that you have too many tables and too many columns to implement all these objects.  But it is simple enough to generate the table and trigger DDL statements from the data dictionary (user_tables, user_tab_columns).