# how to capture old and new column values with Oracle Fine-Grained Auditing (FGA)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, audit-tables

In answers to this (old) question [Auditing in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783298/help-auditing-in-oracle/), it's claimed that Fine-Grained Auditing (FGA) can support the capture of both old and new column values. However, there's no specific guidance about doing so.

I've read the FGA documentation and looked at DBA_AUDIT_POLICIES and DBA_FGA_AUDIT_TRAIL. It seems you can create policies that capture specific column values (conditions) and/or parse the SQL_TEXT and BIND variables, but not clear how you would capture the **old** value.

I'd rather not create a custom audit table. This is on 11gr2 (Enterprise).