# How to create a SQL trigger that will run an export command after every insert / delete

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using OracleDB

the command for exporting a table to a dump file is

runs from sqlplus:

```
$exp USERID=hr/Benmark30 TABLES=(hr.students) FILE=exp_tab.dmp
```

runs from cmd:

```
C:\> sqlplus /as sysdba 

SQL> $exp USERID=hr/Benmark30 TABLES=(hr.students) FILE=exp_tab.dmp
```

How on earth do I create a trigger or an event or a procedure that will:

execute the exporting command after every update and after every delete?

Thanks in advance, Iguana.

Comment: see discussion about same issue here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/679938
draw attention on this:
`If you call this executable from a trigger you haven't commit yet (you can't commit in a trigger) so this executable will not see the data you have changed because this executable will have another Oracle session (it is an external process).`

Comment: `exp` is a command line (operating system)  *program* it is **not** a SQL statement. Because of that it can't be run from SQL\*Plus or from within PL/SQL. You can (and should) **not** do that in a trigger. What if a script runs a million insert statements. Do you really want to export the table a million times? What is the _real_ problem you are trying to solve with that?

Comment: I'm simply trying to backup a table after every insert & delete, into a file locally stored on my machine

Comment: btw `exp` can be run from trigger if you create autonomous transaction function that will run an exe file... but problem here the autonomous transaction won't see the changes until commit...

Comment: you need create `mytable_audit` table as a clone of your original table and insert/delete records into the table. it let you track any changes in the original table. an external process can monitor the table and makes backups if any changes were made

Comment: Can you show a code example?

Comment: see this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783298/help-auditing-in-oracle

Comment: @iguana We could still use some more information on why you are trying to do this.  If you're concerned about losing data, are you aware that Oracle automatically backs up every change using REDO and archive logs?  If your database is setup sanely, then you should be able to pull the plug on the server, destroy any one hard drive, and not lose anything.

Comment: If you want to write the changed data to a file you can use functions in the `UTL_FILE` package to do that. Note that doing so will slow your database to a crawl as you will have to open your flat file, write the new data to this flat file, close the file, and then proceed - all of this in order to do things which are already done quite well (as pointed out by @JonHeller) and arguably much better and faster by the Oracle product. Best of luck.